# How to I use CIAffineTile on Cocoa?

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-image, cifilter, ciimage

I have an CIImage, lets say 500x250 pixels and I am trying to tile it, so it will become a 1000x500 picture, with two rows of two pictures each, like this:

[image]

I am trying to do that with a CIAffineTile on Cocoa (I am not sure if this is the most appropriate filter for that).

As expected the documentation coming from Apple is awfully vague and encrypted.

[image]

Apparently the filter must be called differently from iOS and OSX but the OSX part is enigmatic.

This is the code I have:

What I do is, I create the tile filter than crop it to twice the picture size in each direction + 2, to create a 2 pixel space between them.

```
  // the picture has to translate this amount?
  CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(pictureWidth+2, pictureHeight+2);
  CIFilter *filterTile = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAffineTile"];
  [filterTile setValue:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&translate
                                      objCType:@encode(CGAffineTransform)]
                                        forKey:@"inputTransform"];

  CIVector *cropRect =[CIVector vectorWithX:0
                                          Y:0
                                          Z:2 * pictureWidth+2
                                          W:2 * pictureHeight+2];

  CIFilter *crop = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CICrop"];
  [crop setValue:[filterTile outputImage] forKey:@"inputImage"];
  [crop setValue:cropRect forKey:@"inputRectangle"];
```

this result in an incorrect CIImage. What I see is this:

[image]

What is wrong with the transform? Wasn't it to be supposed the amount of pixels the image has to translate to tile?

The most strange part of all: the transformation can be anything, even the identity transform and the result will be the same.

I have tried to guess how to do it on OSX and imagined something like this:

```
NSAffineTransform *translate = [NSAffineTransform transform];
  [translate translateXBy:(pictureWidth + 2) yBy:(pictureHeight + 2];

  CIFilter *filterTile = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAffineTile"];
  [filterTile setValue:imagem forKey:@"inputImage"];
```

but that ended on a 90 degrees counter clock wise rotated (???) image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conceptually you can think of the CIAffineTile filter as this:

1. tile the image infinitely in X and Y using image.extent.size
2. apply an affine transform

Given this implementation, it is expected behavior that the affine will not have any affect on the gap between the image tiles.

If you want an extra gap between the images then you will need to pad the image with white pixels before using CIAffineTile.  This can be done by using

```
 [[i imageByCompositingOverImage:[CIImage imageWithColor:white]] imageByCroppingToRect:CGRectInset(i.extent,-1,-1)]
```

Here is some code that does a 2x2 tile without padding

```
CGAffineTransform xform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
NSValue *xformObj = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&xform objCType:@encode(CGAffineTransform)];

image = [image imageByApplyingFilter:@"CIAffineTile"
                 withInputParameters:@{kCIInputTransformKey : xformObj} ];
image = [image imageByCroppingToRect:CGRectMake(0,0, 2*pictureWidth, 2*pictureHeight)];
```

Comment: ok, but why the image appears shifted even if the affine is the identity?How do I make the first image start at 0,0 and tile from there in both directions. The image is already shifted. Look at my last picture.

Comment: FWIW, this code worked for me on the Simulator     CGAffineTransform xform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    NSValue *xformObj = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&xform objCType:@encode(CGAffineTransform)];
    
    image = [image imageByApplyingFilter:@"CIAffineTile"
                     withInputParameters:@{kCIInputTransformKey : xformObj} ];
    image = [image imageByCroppingToRect:CGRectMake(0,0,2 * pictureWidth+2, 2 * pictureHeight+2)];